# Override not having expected effect on class

Tags: java, overriding, extends

I am testing out extending a class and overriding functions. With the below I get no compile errors yet when I call JonsClass2.jonsCalcFromClass(2) I still get the response from JonsClass2 not the override from JonsClass3 that I expected.

As an aside I am having to make these calls from main using JonsClass2 JC2 = new JonsClass2(); then JC2.jonsCalcFromClass(2); else the compiler complains that I am calling a non static from a static context.

```
class JonsClass3 extends JonsClass2 {

    @Override
    protected int jonsCalcFromClass(int a) {
        if (a==2) System.out.print("JonsClass3 Called from main using 2 as passed variable  ");
        if (a==1) System.out.print("JonsClass3  from main using 1 as passed variable  ");
        int c = (a + 2);
        return c;
    }

    @Override
    protected double jonsCalcFromClass(double b) {
        System.out.print("This is double line being called in JonsClass3> ");
        double c = (b + 300.10);
        return c;
    }

}

class JonsClass2 {

    protected int jonsCalcFromClass(int a) {
        System.out.print("This is the int line from JonsClass2 being called > ");
        int c = (a + 2);
        return c;
    }

    protected double jonsCalcFromClass(double b) {
        System.out.print("This is double line being called in JonsClass2> ");
        double c = (b + 3.10);
        return c;
    }

}
```

Comment: To achieve that, when instantiate the JC2, should be `JonsClass2 JC2 = new JonsClass3 ();`

Comment: If you override a method in a Class `X` that override only applies *to instances of class `X`* (and subclasses of `X`, if they don't override it themselves). Instances of the base class will of course still use the base version of the method. That's called polymorphism (i.e. the actual code to be executed depends on the actual type of the object you call it on) and is the whole idea behind overriding.

Comment: Please show the code of the ``public static void main(String[] args)`` method.

Comment: Some have asked for the Main method I used : public class SandPit {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JonsClass2 jc2 = new JonsClass2();
        jc2.jonsCalcFromClass(2);

Comment: What I was expecting is that JonsClass3 extends JonsClass2 would force JonsClass2 to use the overridden methods from JonsClass3. If the Override only applies to instances of JonsClass3 then I have misunderstood how it applies. I assume then it works best for overriding one method while not overriding others so as to take advantage of methods in the parent class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the compiler complains that I am calling a non static from a static
> context.

We can't call non-static methods from a static method (like main) directly. because a static method is a class' method. but a non-static method is object method so we should call it on an object. so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
  jonsCalcFromClass(1) // compile error

  JonsClass2 JC2 = new JonsClass3()
  JC2.jonsCalcFromClass(1) // correct
}
```

If you want polymorphism behaviour you should do this:
 `JonsClass2 JC2 = new JonsClass3 ();`

Answer (score 2):

Pay attention on what instanse you create.

```
JonsClass2 js2 = new JonsClass2();
JonsClass2 js3 = new JonsClass3();
js2.jonsCalcFromClass(2);   // This is the int line from JonsClass2 being called >
js3.jonsCalcFromClass(2);   //JonsClass3 Called from main using 2 as passed variable
```

In your example `onsClass2 JC2 = new JonsClass2();` you create instance of `JonsClass2`, so methods from `JonsClass3` will not be called.